# Guice config error: Could not find a suitable constructor

Tags: java, guice

I have class that I am trying to instantiate via Guice but I am getting:

`Could not find a suitable constructor in com.workspace.myclass. Classes must have either one (and only one) constructor annotated with @Inject or a zero-argument constructor that is not private.`

My code looks something like:

```
public class MyModule extends AbstractModule {

    @Override
    protected void configure() { }

    myClass<obj> getMyClass(arg1, arg2) {
        Object someObj = new someObj(arg1);
        return myClass<>(someObj, s -> new Obj(arg2, s.getMethod()));
    }
}

public myClass<T extends someClass> {

    public myClass(arg1, Function<obj<T>, obj2<T>> arg2) {

    }

}

public static void main(args[]) {

    Injector injector = createInjector(new MyModule());
    MyClass myClass = injector.getInstance(MyClass.class);
}
```

Is Guice unable to resolve the lambda to the constructor for MyClass?

Comment: Assuming you mean `MyClass` everywhere, not `myClass`, the main issue is that Guice has no idea what `T` should be.  Also, if you want to use `getMyClass()` as a provider method, it needs `@Provides`

Answer (score 0):

Guice did not like that I gave in the module the return type `myClass<obj>` from getMyClass and works with just return `myClass`.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you are missing the @Provides annotation in your getMyClass method
Did you try to bind using the binder inside the configure method?

Comment: I left that out of my original post but I do have the Provides annotation